# Using system Sound to play sounds

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

Here is the code:

```
-(void)stop
{
    NSLog(@"Disposing Sounds");
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID (soundID);
    //AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion (soundID);
}

static void completionCallback (SystemSoundID  mySSID, void* myself) {
    NSLog(@"completion Callback");
}
- (void) playall: (id) sender {

    [self stop];

    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (soundID,NULL,NULL,
     completionCallback,
     (void*) self);


    OSStatus err = kAudioServicesNoError;
    NSString *aiffPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"slide1" ofType:@"m4a"];
    NSURL *aiffURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:aiffPath];
    err = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) aiffURL, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
    NSLog(@"Done Playing");
}
```

Output:

```
Disposing Sounds
Done Playing
```

In actual no sound gets play at all and completion call back isn't called as well. Any idea what could be wrong here?
I want to stop any previous sound before playing current.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the only supported files are .caf, .aif, or .wav:

> To play your own sounds, add the sound
>   file to your application bundle; the
>   sound file must adhere to the
>   following requirements:
>
> - Must be .caf, .aif, or .wav files.
> - The audio data in the file must be in    PCM or IMA/ADPCM (IMA4) format.
> - The file's audio duration must be less    than 30 seconds.

[Audio & Video Coding How-To's](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/index.html#PLAYBACK-PLAY_SHORT_SOUNDS_AND_ALERTS)

Answer (score 0):

What does err contain? From that you should be able to infer the problem.

Comment: I printed err using NSLog and apears to be (null)

Comment: Do you mean (null) or zero? I think you need to be a little more cautious with your NSLog... (null) is not an integer... ;)

Comment: i did this:


NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);

so i guess i am printing string, and it tells me its "(null)" on console.

Comment: NSLog(@"Error: %d", err); please. err is an OSStatus, which is of integer type.

Comment: Great. Now set err=AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); and see what err returns there.

Comment: gives: "error: void values not ignored as its ought to be" i am using Iphone SDK 3 beta 2 with simulator 3.1

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I'm dealing with the same behavior - it happens whenever the ringer is muted.  I can't find a way to override this (even with AudioSessionInitialize and kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory).

Answer (score 0):

You can use AudioToolBox framework for this:

```
CFBundleRef mainbundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainbundle, CFSTR("tap"), CFSTR("aif"), NULL);
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundFileObject);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1100);
```